# .NET Core snapcraft crosscompile for Raspberrypi3

Tags: snap

I am attempting to create a snap to run on a Raspberry Pi 3.

Here is my snapcraft.yaml:

```
name: rqdq-cross-hello
version: "1.00"
summary: NET Hello, the "hello world" snap
description: .NET Hello prints a friendly greeting.
grade: stable
confinement: strict
architectures: [armhf]

apps:
  hello:
    command: publish/hello

parts:
  net-hello:
    plugin: dump
    source: src/bin
    stage-packages:
      - libunwind8
      - libicu55
```

And here are the commands I use to build it (amd64 host):

```
dotnet publish -r linux-arm -o bin/publish src/hello.csproj

snapcraft cleanbuild --targetarch armhf
```

The snap builds fine, but when I install this on a rasberrypi3 (running Ubuntu CORE) I get:

```
/snap/rqdq-cross-hello/4/command-hello.wrapper: 6: exec: /snap/rqdq-cross-hello/4/publish/hello: Accessing a corrupted shared library
```

Full source here:
https://github.com/rquackenbush/rqdq-cross-test

Answer (score 0):

I have moved this forward a bit, but it crashes differently now.

```
$ rqdq-hello.hello
FailFast:
Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system. Set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to true if you want to run with no globalization support.

   at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String)
   at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode.GetGlobalizationInvariantMode()
   at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode..cctor()
   at System.Globalization.CultureData.CreateCultureWithInvariantData()
   at System.Globalization.CultureData.get_Invariant()
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..cctor()
   at System.StringComparer..cctor()
   at System.AppDomain.InitializeCompatibilityFlags()
   at System.AppDomain.CreateAppDomainManager()
   at System.AppDomain.Setup(System.Object)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I removed the reference to `libc6` and a duplicate line from `stage-packages`.

```
name: rqdq-hello
version: "2.12"
summary: NET Hello, the "hello world" snap
description: .NET Hello prints a friendly greeting.
grade: stable
confinement: strict
architectures: 
  - armhf

apps:
  hello:
    command: publish/hello

parts:
  net-hello:
    build-attributes: [no-system-libraries]
    plugin: dump
    source: src/bin
    stage-packages:
      - libunwind8
      - libicu55
      - icu-devtools
      - libcurl3
      - libgcc1
      - libgssapi-krb5-2
      - libicu-dev
      - liblttng-ust0
      - libstdc++6
      - libuuid1
      - wget
      - zlib1g
```